# BeginInvoke on array of threads in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, restart, begininvoke, pause

I Sorry by my bad english. I found this code. Work fine, but I cant display a text in a label.

This is a code that allows me to have several open tasks, but I can also pause them at any time and re-start them again. I have tried to carry out all the examples here but I have not found the right one.

```
    Public Class Form1

    Dim theThrdsL As New Object
    Dim theThrds As New Dictionary(Of String, Tareas)

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        'stop threads
        For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Tareas) In theThrds
            kvp.Value.isRun = False 'tell them not to run
            kvp.Value.suspendthis.Set() 'set to not suspended 
            kvp.Value.Tarea.Join() 'wait for thread to end
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Enabled = False
        For x As Integer = 0 To 4 'start some threads
            Dim foo As New Tareas 'set up thread
            foo.myKey = x.ToString 'decoration
            foo.Tarea = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf foo.dowork) 'set up the worker
            Threading.Monitor.Enter(theThrdsL) 'add thread to list
            theThrds.Add(x.ToString, foo)
            Threading.Monitor.Exit(theThrdsL)
            foo.Tarea.Start() 'start the worker
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If theThrds.Count > 0 Then theThrds("0").suspendthis.Reset() 'suspend thread 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If theThrds.Count > 0 Then theThrds("0").suspendthis.Set() 'restart thread 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetLabelText(ByVal text As String)
        If Label1.InvokeRequired Then
            Label1.Invoke(New SetText(AddressOf SetLabelText), text)
        Else
            Label1.Text = text
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Delegate Sub SetText(ByVal text As String)

Class Tareas
    Property Tarea As Threading.Thread
    Property suspendthis As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(True)
    Property myKey As String
    Property isRun As Boolean = True

    Public Sub dowork(ByVal param_objx As Object)
        'Debug.WriteLine("S-> " & Me.myKey) 'show start
        Do While Me.isRun
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            If Me.suspendthis.WaitOne Then
                Debug.WriteLine(Me.myKey & " " & DateTime.Now)
            Else
                Me.suspendthis.WaitOne() 'block indefinitely
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the problem. I can not seem to show the text on the label. I received:

*"Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created"*

```
        Public Sub dowork(ByVal param_objx As Object)
        'Debug.WriteLine("S-> " & Me.myKey) 'show start
        Do While Me.isRun
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            If Me.suspendthis.WaitOne Then
                Debug.WriteLine(Me.myKey & " " & DateTime.Now)

              ** ---------------------------------- **
              **The problem:**

                Form1.Label1.BeginInvoke(Sub() Form1.Label1.Text = "HELLO WORLD") 
              ** ---------------------------------- **                  

            Else
                Me.suspendthis.WaitOne() 'block indefinitely
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to set the `Text` of `Label1` then you call `SetLabelText`.  It will work from any thread, although it's not necessary if you know you're already on the UI thread.

Comment: That said, you'll need a reference to the form the `Label` is on.  A better way would be to have the `Tareas` class raise an event but that is another level of complexity.  The simplest way is for the form to pass a reference to itself, i.e. `Me`, into the `Tareas` object when it creates it.  That means that you need to add a way to pass it in and a place to store it once it's in.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @jmcilhinney. I have done it but it sends me: **Invoke or BeginInvoke can not be called on a control until the handle window has been created** I have read a lot but I have not been able to solve it. I just modified the post in the problem, read it, please.

Comment: Your issue is that you are using the _default_ Form1 instance  in your `dowork` method.  The default instance is a thread specific property; i.e. each thread gets its own instance of Form1.  Since only the UI thread Form1 is visible, you are getting the "handle not created" error.  The solution is to follow jmcilhinney's advice and pass the proper Form1 instance to each instance of `Tareas` and use that passed instance in your code.

Comment: Thanks  @TnTinMn. Can you help me with the dowork() code only a small part, please?.

Comment: Thanks to TnTinMn, but especially to @Jmcilhinney. Problem solved.